# Jsfiddle unclosed regular expression

Tags: reactjs, jsx, jsfiddle

[image]Anyone know why jsfiddle is giving me this error when testing jsx.

> unclosed regular expression

https://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/LzdfLy53/

```
const combobox = () => (
    <div id="box">
    working
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<combobox />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

-

Comment: This is not a duplicate as I'm getting a different error of unclosed regular expression. Giving my component a uppercase doesn't solve this issue. But to your point it should be a uppercase.

Comment: Bad closing of this question. I had a very similar problem. The referenced "duplicate" didn't help.

This should be a bug by jsfiddle as my exact code works with other online playgrounds.